# Outlook Custom field filtering using MAPI

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I try to filter custom properties get contacts in a Outlook. I saved user property call "SyncValue". It have string values. And I try to check these values and get the contactitem have that property value.

```
Outlook.ContactItem contactItem = null;
string syncVal = (char)34 + "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/SyncValue" + (char)34;
Outlook.MAPIFolder contacts = Globals.objNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
Outlook.Items contactItems = contacts.Items;
string filter = "WHERE (" + syncVal + " = 'True')";
contactItem = contactItems.Find(filter) as Outlook.ContactItem;
```

Comment: And what is the problem? What is the data type of the property? OOM by default assumes a string, and you most likely have a boolean.

Comment: I saved property as a string value "True" or "False". Problem is when getting ContactItems it occur error -"Condition is not valid"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter string must be prefixed with `@SQL=`. You should not use "WHERE":

```
string filter = "@SQL=" + syncVal + " = 'True')";
```

Comment: @dimitry Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, It gets the Contactitem which have that custom properties

Comment: Please mark the reply as the answer if it answers your question. Thanks!.